# C#, Modulo operation gives different result than a calculator

Tags: c#, math, modulo

So I wanted to write this method : 142^23 (mod 187), and using any calculator I get the result 65 but with this piece of code : 
`double number = Math.Pow(142, 23) % 187`
I get a result of 53. Why is this, and what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: and what calculator are we talking about here?

Comment: @Steve *any* calculator!

Comment: `BigInteger.ModPow(142, 23, 187)` gives me 65.  I suspect the number is too large so `double` is having to sacrifice precision.  I don't know how to prove this though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Math.Pow(142, 23)` is too big to accurately be represented by a double. So your modulus is done on a lossy calculation.

This will give the correct answer:

```
BigInteger.ModPow(142, 23, 187);
```

`BigInteger` can be found in the `System.Numerics` namespace and assembly.

You can also implement this yourself efficiently if you want like so for integers of the size you were using in your question.

```
private static int ModPow(int basenum, int exponent, int modulus)
{
    if (modulus == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int result = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < exponent; i++)
    {
        result = (result * basenum) % modulus;
    }
    return result;
}
```

`BigInteger` does something more clever with binary exponentiation which will work better with truly huge number.

Answer (score 2):

If we use `BigInteger` to compute the *full* result of the exponential:

```
var bi = BigInteger.Pow(142, 23);
Debug.WriteLine(bi);
```

We get this very large number:

```
31814999504641997296916177121902819369397243609088
or
3.1814999504642E+49
```

If we then convert that value to a double, to cause a loss of precision, and then back to a `BigInteger`:

```
var d = (double) bi;
bi = new BigInteger(d);
Debug.WriteLine(bi);
```

We get:

```
31814999504641997296916177121902819369397243609088  -- BigInteger
31814999504641993108158684988768059669621048868864  -- BigInteger -> double -> BigInteger
                ^ oh no mah precision
```

In hexadecimal, where the loss of precision is more obvious:

```
15C4 C9EB 18CD 25CE 858D 6C2D C3E5 D319 BC9B 8000 00
15C4 C9EB 18CD 2500 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00   
                 ^ oh no mah precision
```

You'll notice that the loss of precision occurs at the 17th decimal digit, or the 14th hexadecimal digit.

Why?

[A `double` is stored using IEEE-754 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format):

```
Significand or mantissa:          0-51
Exponent:                         52-62
Sign (0 = Positive, 1 = Negative) 63
```

The key here is 52 bits for the mantissa.  Our 14 hexadecimal digits are 56 bits, close to the 52-bit limit.  How can we account for the 4-bit discrepancy?

*(I think I made a mistake in the explanation that follows.  If someone can point it out, I would be grateful)*

The last unchanged hex digit is `C`, or `1100` in binary; since the last two bits are zeroes, our number was encoded in 54 bits, not 56.  So, it's actually a 2-bit discrepancy.

How do we account for the last two bits?  This is due to how the fractional component of IEEE-754 is determined.  It's been a long time since I did this, so I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: @vcsjones I couldn't fully explain the loss of precision in my comment, so I've been on a mission.  its been a fun and challenging question to answer.  I'm still working on the last two bits.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

```
BigInteger D = 353068955875873;
BigInteger E = 324734382257802;
BigInteger F = 752748311613664;
D ^ E % F
112448018451627

however:
BigInteger.ModPow(D, E, F)
116860072266913
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.